# Tightness for law of discrete time martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, weak-convergence

Suppose $\{M_n^k,n=1,2,\cdots,N\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of martingale on a fixed probability space. Suppose the terminal distributions $\mu_k=\mathcal L(M_N^k), k=1,2,...$ is a tight sequence. I am wondering if the laws of $\{M_n^k\}$ is tight or not.

In general, I am interested in knowing if there are any general criterions for tightness of laws of discrete time martingales.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by a sequence of martingale? That for all $k$, $(M_n^k)_n$ is a martingale or that for all $n$, $(M_n^k)_k$ is a martingale?

Comment: For fixed $k$, $(M_n^k)_{n=1}^N$ is a martingale. Sorry for the confusion.